# Unordered List Breaks Sticky Footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to create a responsive template and I'm having issues with an unordered list breaking my sticky footer.

It seems that specifically when I don't include the li's, keeping the ul, the footer likes to stick, but the li's don't actually appear to be sticking out of the bottom when included... tried inspecting, FF 3d modeling, etc to look around for that any sign of that...

[link to page](http://sb.colbyfayock.com/temp), [direct css link](http://sb.colbyfayock.com/temp/style.css)

It's simply the extra space below the footer, can't pinpoint it though.
I haven't been able to find a specific sticky issue like this
Any help? Thanks

Update: Another thing I noticed, when I remove the doctype, it works just fine. I'm using the html5 doctype.

Update 2: Setting the ul to block fixes it, as its currently inline-table, but that removes the ability to have it set to the width of its childs and align it via text-align. im thinking it would be better practice to keep inline-table somehow rather than using floats...

Update 3: Set UL to block, LI to inline,table and that reduce the margin, still about a pixel remaining making overflow still happen... only issue now is the height/line-height is messing up and now allowing the background color change on hover to full extend

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the bottom of your css and it stuck

```
 #footer{top:auto; bottom:0;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

But this is just a quick lazy fix, I strongly advise that you backtrack though your code, it seems very complex for such a simple structure, try to reduce the branching elements in the css.

Comment: Thanks. I mean the branching in there is to collapse the layout for mobile or specifically screen size <640px, if that's what you meant. I tried to condense everything mostly that i could

Comment: Have you consided a seperate mobile site via redirect, a html/css desktop/mobile framework separate or as a combination? Try: http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile, http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/

Comment: Hm, I haven't actually considered that. Will definitely take a look, thanks! Hoping for now to try and learn first what makes the ul/li, or whatever container it is, in the site above behave weird though.